# Travelling on hoshanah raba

Tags: halacha, travel, vehicles-transportation, hoshana-rabbah

Is it allowed for one to travel by car on Hoshana Rabbah?
If so, what are the sources for this?

Comment: Remember to share as much of your previous research and motivation to ask. Specifically what makes you think it might be forbidden? There are many outings organized on Chol Hamoed, what makes you think they might be forbidden?

Comment: This post should not have been gang-downvoted. Such action lacks maturity. If a new person asks our community something that is bothering them, there are many good ways to handle it. 1) In a comment, explain that we do not wish to answer Halachic questions that should be asked to their Rabbi. 2) Do not overly require an OP to divine why they think it may be forbidden etc. 3) Point them to an Orthodox hotline that might offer a Rav's time and a kosher psak. In any case, not upvoting, or one downvote suffices. Kudos to Joel K for a respectful handling of the question in his answer below.

Comment: It is important to have a Rabbi/Rav for answering practical Halachic questions. I do not know if this is the right thing for you personally, but you might consider calling this hotline, and asking them for help when you have questions, or help finding a Rav in your area. I have found them to be very helpul. Rav Binyomin Forst's hotline: 516-239-2500 / 718-337-8370. (5 towns, NY). You can also use the internet to search for an Orthodox Rabbi/Congregation in or near your town. Have a sweet new year. :)

Answer (score 4):

Hoshanah Rabbah is the final day of Chol Hamoed Sukkot. As such (to quote from [this chabad.org article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1000452/jewish/Chol-Hamoed.htm)):

> On the full-fledged festival days of Passover and Sukkot we are prohibited from creative work, much like Shabbat (with exceptions).
>
> On Chol Hamoed, however, we are permitted to do many of these activities. For example, we may use electricity or drive a car.

However, as noted in [this ou.org article](https://www.ou.org/holidays/sukkot/hilchos-chol-hamoed/):

> What is important to keep in mind is that even the Melachos that are permitted on Chol Hamoed are only permitted if they are done l’tzorech hamoed (for the sake of Chol Hamoed, i.e. in order to benefit from them on Chol Hamoed).

Comment: Thank you, I'm traveling to get to a kibbutz for simchat Torah.